# \titleUL command definition

Tags: titles

For the life of me I cannot understand why `\titleUL` is not working when I compile. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx, imakeidx, afterpage}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsthm, epigraph, etoolbox, amssymb}
%\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}

%----------------WATER MARK AND TITLE--------------
\newcommand*{\titleUL}{\begingroup
\drop=0.1\textheight
\vspace*{\drop}
\begin{center}
{\LARGE\textsc{UNIVERSIDAD NACIONAL AUT\'ONOMA DE M\'EXICO}\\[\drop]
% University logo
{\LARGE \plogo}\\[\drop]
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\par
\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
{\huge\bfseries Encyclop\ae dia Formul\ae\\
\large --- in N pages, with T tables ---}\\
[0.5\baselineskip]
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\par
\vfill
{\Large\textsc{The\EncFortnote{\texttt{email address}} Candidate}}
\vfill
City, Country
\vfill
{\large The Date}
\end{center}%
\endgroup}
}
\setcounter{page}{0}
%-------------------------------------------------
\SetWatermarkText{DRAFT}
\SetWatermarkScale{5}
\makeindex[columns=2, intoc]
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\titleUL

%-------------------COVER PAGE page 0-------------------%

%------------------------------------------------------
\frontmatter
\newpage            % false page i.
\newpage            % false page ii.
%--------------------TITLE PAGE iii------------------------%
\author{Karl Ruprecht Kr\"{o}nen}   % agregar adscripcion e.g. Ph.D. FRS.
\title{Encyclop\ae dia Formul\ae}
% nombre de la casa editora
% nombre del resivor tecnico con sus adscripciones
\date{}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: What happens? Don't you get an error message? Maybe that `\plogo` is not defined? And `\EncFortnote`? Or...?

Comment: @cfr
\EncFornote was corrected to \footnote sorry.
I get the following errors:
    `\EncFor.tex:57 Undefined control sequence \titleUL`
    `Missing number, treated as zero \titleUL`
    `EncFor.tex:57 Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) \titleUL'`

Comment: You probably want `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` but what is `\plogo`? Can you minimise your example? It will help you to find the problem. Right now it is really far from being minimal.

Comment: @cfr Sorry, I want to reproduce a title page taken from here:

http://ftp.yzu.edu.tw/CTAN/info/latex-samples/TitlePages/titlepages.pdf

There must be a better way than loading everything he is attempting to include.

Comment: You mean from [here](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlepages)? Well, yes. I expect that the author is loading a whole bunch of stuff for a whole set of different title pages. Could you say *which* you are trying to reproduce? And please do think about minimising your example. If glossaries and nomenclature etc. are not part of the problem, they should not be part of your example. Does the problem really depend on inclusion of a bibliography? When you post an example you are claiming that removing any of it resolves the problem....

Comment: @cfr I am trying to reproduce the one in page 21.
What do you mean with minimise? Im afraid if I omit a part of my code something will be missed.

Comment: Your question is about the title. Why do we need a bunch of acronyms, a glossary, a bit on probability and a bibliography? Only what is relevant to the question should be in your code.

Comment: @cfr

I've updated the code, sorry.

Comment: No need to be sorry. Unlike many new users, you provided a complete document - that gets you gold stars even if you maybe provided a little more than we needed ;). Hopefully, my answer will help. But you should have said where you got the code from both because it is polite and because it would have made it a lot easier to figure out what you were trying to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it this is the target:

[image: title page]

This is modified from Peter Wilson's [`titlepages.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/latex-samples/TitlePages/titlepages.tex) available as part of his package [titlepages](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlepages).

I've not really changed the code. I wouldn't probably do it this way, but it works. I have set the page style to empty to avoid the page number which looks odd. And I omitted the grouping which I don't think we need here.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry,url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand*{\plogo}{\fbox{$\mathcal{PL}$}}
\newdimen\drop
\newcommand*{\titleUL}{%
  \drop=0.1\textheight
  \vspace*{\drop}
  \begin{center}
    {\LARGE\textsc{THE UNIVERSITY}}\\[\drop]
    % University logo
    {\LARGE \plogo}\thispagestyle{empty}\\[\drop]

    \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\par
    \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
    {\huge\bfseries Conundrums: An Investigation of Mind Puzzles\\
      \large --- in N pages, with T tables ---}\\[0.5\baselineskip]
    \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\par

    \vfill

    % fake a footnote reference here
    {\Large\textsc{The\textsuperscript{1} Candidate}}

    \vfill

    City, Country

    \vfill

    {\large The Date}
  \end{center}

  % faked footnote
  \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
  \noindent\rule{0.4\textwidth}{0.4pt} \\
  \textsuperscript{1} \url{email.address}
}
\begin{document}
  \titleUL
\end{document}
```